# Error using `hbox` and `tcblisting`

Tags: tcolorbox

The following example only seems to work if I remove the `hbox` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}


\newtcblisting[auto counter,list inside=example]{example}[2][]{%
    title=#2,
    #1,
    %hbox,%hbox doesn't work?
    center,
    colback=green!20,
    colbacktitle=green!50,
    colframe=green,
    %listing only,
    lower separated=false,%remove lines inside
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,coltitle=black,titlerule=0pt,enhanced,drop fuzzy shadow}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[listing side text]{An example}
\textbf{bold text}

\textit{italics text}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I include `hbox`, `tcolorbox` generates an error (`Undefined control sequence. \end{example}`) and the content is misaligned (too little space between the left side and the right side):

[image]

If I use the option `listing only`, everything works fine.

Comment: The documentation for hbox says the following: "This is the default mode for \tcbox. The content cannot have a lower part and cannot be broken. The colored box is sized according to the dimensions of the content." AFAIK the "text" of a listing is treated as lower part.

Comment: @TeXnician: You mean the `code output` of the TeX listing is treated as `lower box`. `listings only` displays the TeX code only in the upper part and with this `hbox` works, of course

Comment: I see. I was hoping there as a workaround. Anyway, a box spanning the whole text width doesn't bother much, and we can still specify its width.

Comment: @TeXnician: You wrote "text" of a listing -- this could be misunderstood as the code listing itself

Comment: @Joseph You won't have much luck with "automatic" adjustments of the width if you like to have that lower box intact. A manual width adjustment however can be done.

Comment: @TeXnician: No, `listing side text` is displaying code left and 'compiled' code right (given the usual orientation of 'side by side' in `tcolorbox`), so it is 'upper' and 'lower' box. I find the word 'text' in in the options rather misleading.

Comment: @Joseph: By the way, you should add `#1` at the end of your code options, not right at the start, where following code options override your settings

Comment: @TeXnician: Of course you're right about `hbox` -- as soon there is a lower part `hbox` fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation of `tcolorbox` you'll find the following aspect for `capture=hbox` (which `hbox` stands for):

> This is the default mode for `\tcbox`. The content cannot have a lower part and cannot be broken. The colored box is sized according to the dimensions of the content.

You are using the option `listing side text` which typesets the output (`text`) as the lower part/lower box of the tcolorbox. This contradicts "cannot have a lower part".

So the only way to get accurate width adjustments is a manual one. The automated way doesn't work for your use case.